# IPV6 range to CIDR

Tags: get, range, ipv6, cidr

How can I write Java program that takes IPV6 start and end ip address and give me possible list of CIDR in String I do have reference of 
 this [http://facedroid.blogspot.com/2010/06/ip-range-to-cidr.html]. But it works only with IPV4 I also need for IPV6.

Answer (score 0):

The [open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) can do this for you.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of the IPAddress library.

Here is sample code to do it:

```
static void toPrefixBlocks(String str1, String str2) {
    IPAddressString string1 = new IPAddressString(str1);
    IPAddressString string2 = new IPAddressString(str2);
    IPAddress one = string1.getAddress(), two = string2.getAddress();
    IPAddressSeqRange range = one.toSequentialRange(two);
    System.out.println("starting with range " + range);
    IPAddress blocks[] = range.spanWithPrefixBlocks();
    System.out.println("prefix blocks are " + Arrays.asList(blocks));
}
```

The code actually works the same for both IPv6 and IPv4.  Since you specify IPv6, here is an IPv6 example:

```
toPrefixBlocks("2001:db8:abcd:0012:1::","2001:db8:abcd:0012:3::");
```

The output is:

```
starting with range 2001:db8:abcd:12:1:: -> 2001:db8:abcd:12:3::
prefix blocks are [2001:db8:abcd:12:1::/80, 2001:db8:abcd:12:2::/80, 2001:db8:abcd:12:3::/128]
```